# Using python modules in R reticulate with hyphens?

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I'm trying to import a module using the `reticulate library` in `R`, however the library fails to import because it has a hyphen in it. In specific, it is the `bitmex-ws` module. `py_install("bitmex-ws")` works no problem, but the error is when trying to import, I receive a `module not found error`.

Comment: How are you trying to import the module? Python identifiers can’t have hyphens, so I doubt this is related to reticulate. Did you mean to import `bitmex_websocket`?

Answer (score 1):

You may want `import bitmex_websocket`.

See example usage here: https://pypi.org/project/bitmex-ws/